# Alignment Issue in Android

Tags: android, layout

How do I solve these icon, divider and listview alignment issue. It comes perfect for some screens but for other screens, it eases out. Below is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="2dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dip"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="15dip"
            android:paddingTop="15dip"
            android:background="#e7ebee"
            />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_drawable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"` to the `LinearLayout` with the id of **Text**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Paste Following Code:

It will work for any Screen

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#666666" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_summary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/list_item_entry_title"
        android:layout_below="@id/list_item_entry_title"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#666666" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_entry_drawable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="2dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/list_item_entry_drawable"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_item_entry_drawable"
    android:background="#e7ebee"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:paddingTop="15dip" />
```